# Manage Google Login with Firebase when user login second time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm developing an Android application that uses Firebase and to login I use Google login.
 I want to store extras information about users, like `email`, `name` and other information.
For this reason I created a separate branch on Firebase called `users` and when a user successfully login I write those information in that branch.
This approach works good with authentication with username and password, because **SignUp** and **SignIn** are managed separately with different methods.
With Google authentication instead, if I'm right, I can only sign in (the first sign in works like sign up).
[Firebase authentication with Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin)

I apply the example provided in the Firebase documentation by calling inside the method `updateUI()` (which is called when the Google SignIn has success) defined there the following method:

```
    void addUser(User user) {
      databasereference.child(USERS).child(user.getuserid()).setvalue(user);
    }
```

where `databasereference` is the root of my database. So the updateUI method should looks like this:

```
void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    if(user != null) {
        User myUser = new User(user.getDisplayName(), user.getEmail(), user.getUid());
        addUser(myUser);
    }
}
```

If it's correct, I don't know how to manage this situation:

1. I login correctly the first time
2. I do something (add information about me)
3. I logout
4. I login again

In that case obviously I overwrite all the previous information because I call again the method `addUser()` without any check.
At the same time, I think that use a listener under `users` branch (and specific `userId`) is not correct because I have to download all the information about the single user.

**Does exist a way to manage the second time I login with Google?** 
In the case the approach I used is correct, **the only way to check if a user exists yet when he logins is to download his information from my `USERS`' branch or there is another way? What type of check can I do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you have a database which looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- users
          |
          --- uid1
          |
          --- uid2
```

To check the existens of a user you need to attach a listener on `users` node and use `exists()` method like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            //Create user
        } else {
            //Do something else
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

In which `uid` is the id of the user which you want to check if exists.

Comment: Thank you. But in this way, in the case the user already exists, I'll download all his branch or not?

Comment: It does not download again.

Comment: Not because is cached. It is because this is the way this method works. To have a cache you need to enable persistens. Good luck!